# jQuery: use the "name" as img "src"

Tags: jquery, image, src

my question:
i have an img tag

```
<img class="myclassname" src="1.jpg" name="2.jpg">
```

i'd like to change the img source (currently 1.jpg) to the one i wrote in the "name" attribute (2.jpg) using jquery.

why this does not work?

```
$(".myclassname").attr("src", $(this).attr("name"));
```

thanks for any help! greets mafka

(ps: the script is more complex, of course, but this is the problem i stuck)

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because `this` doesn't have the context you'd like. It will actuayll refer to the `window` object. If you follow Daniel's tips, it should work. Google "Javascript closure" to learn more.

Comment: I would use the selector `img.myclassname` to make sure you are only grabbing IMG tags

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to iterate over all tags with that classname, as $(this) is not known in that context.

Try something like:

```
$(".myclassname").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".myclassname").each(function (){
$(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Problem with your code is that jQuery does not know what "this" in that context is.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps...

```
        $(".test").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("name"));
            alert($(this).attr("src"));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the reference to myclassname in a variable. Will make your script more clear to read also:

```
var _myClassname = $(".myclassname");
_myClassname.attr("src", _myClassname.attr("name"));
```